# Database / geolocation. Finding people nearby

Tags: mongodb, web, geolocation, location, coordinates

I am currently trying to create a small web app that will find other people nearby who are using it as well.

When I use the geolocation feature, I save the "Last known location" of the user on the server for about an hour, after which I remove the location from the database collection (I use MongoDb)

Every time, I compare the position with all the people who have recently checked-in (those in the location collection), to find people who are close.

This method doesn't seem efficient though, the number of people could be huge, which would mean iterating a long list and comparing positions with people who are in different countries.

I'm thinking about dividing into multiple tables for each country or timezone. Which would prevent the app from searching too far.

Any advice or thoughts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use MongoDB 2.4's geospatial support here. For each user, store the location in the following format (it's GeoJSON):

```
{
    _id: ...,
    name: ...,
    last_known_location: { 
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ longitude, latitude ]
    }
}
```

And set the following index:

```
db.location.ensureIndex( { last_known_location: "2dsphere" } );
```

Now you can very easily search for all the people close to the current user, with the following query:

```
db.location.find( {
    last_known_location: {
        $near: { 
            $geometry: { 
                "type" : "Point", 
                "coordinates" : [ -0.1485302, 51.5250157 ] 
            }
        }, 
        $maxDistance: 10 
    } 
} );
```

With $maxDistance you can control how many meters away from the provided coordinates the "closest" users might be.